# Session com IList em asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, session

Tem como eu criar uma Session com valores de um array do tipo IList no asp.net mvc5?

Se tiver, como eu faço o foreach para pegar essas informações no html da view?

Comment: é a versão core?

Comment: E ai deu certo a solução ???

Comment: Virgilio, pra ser sincero eu não testei, pois minha intenção não era receber o return como Model, eu queria chamá-lo direto pelo @Session. Mas sua resposta foi de grande valia, independente do retorno eu não sabia como passar um array para Session. Vou guardar sua resposta para consultas futuras.

Comment: Se a resposta falta alguma coisa, de uma melhorada na sua pergunta que o resto ficará como complemento, e por favor se for útil assinale como resposta, mas, edite sua pergunta e coloque realmente o que precisa (talvez eu não tem entendido o foco real?

Answer (score 0):

> Tem como eu criar uma `Session` com valores de um array do tipo `IList` no Asp.Net Mvc5?

Tem sim, é só adicionar o valor na sessão da seguinte forma:

Configure a aplicação para saber que precisa utilizar o recurso de `Session`, abra o arquivo na raiz do seu site `Startup.cs` e configure dois método:

- `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

  ```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
  {
      services.AddMvc();

      services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
      services.AddSession(); // adicionando a session
  }
  ```

e

- `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)`

  ```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
      app.UseSession(); // adicionando session.

      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          app.UseBrowserLink();
      }
      else
      {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
      }

      app.UseStaticFiles();

      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });     
  }
  ```

---

Agora nos métodos de qualquer `Controller`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{            

    IList<string> textos = new List<string>();
    textos.Add("texto 1");
    textos.Add("texto 2");
    textos.Add("texto 3");
    textos.Add("texto 5");

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Lista", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(textos));

    return View();
}
```

No código foi criado uma lista de texto e foi guardada na sessão com o nome de **Lista** mas, foi convertido a lista naquilo que a sessão entende que é um texto.

Para voltar ao que era antes, ou seja, uma lista de texto tem que utilizar o processo inverso, exemplo:

```
IList<string> textos = JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<List<string>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lista"));
```

nas versão anteriores isso é muito mais prático, mas, hoje na versão `Core` é assim, mas, existe um código que pode ser utilizado em um método de extensão de maneira bem mais simples, observe:

```
public static class Utils
{

    public static void SetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (session.Keys.Contains(key))
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(session.GetString(key));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
        throw new Exception("Key no present");
    }

}
```

com esses dois métodos de extensão cria um atalho melhor no seu código e pode ser resumido a isso:

***Gravar na Session:***

```
IList<string> textos = new List<string>();
textos.Add("texto 1");
textos.Add("texto 2");
textos.Add("texto 3");
textos.Add("texto 5");

HttpContext.Session.SetObject("Lista", textos);
```

***Recuperar da Session:***

```
IList<string> textos = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<IList<string>>("Lista");
```

> Se tiver, como eu faço o `foreach` para pegar essas informações no html da view?

Como é sabido, existe sim, a primeira parte foi respondida para passar para `View` faça o seguinte:

```
public IActionResult About()
{
    IList<string> textos = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<IList<string>>("Lista");
    return View(textos);
}
```

e na `View` coloque a configuração em `@model` do tipo que precisa depois é só fazer um `foreach`:

```
@model List<string>

@foreach(string texto in Model)
{
    <div>@texto</div>
}
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [An introduction to Session storage in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/)
- [Session State In ASP.NET Core](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/session-state-in-asp-net-core/)